# how to convert tree query set into dictionary?

Tags: django, django-mptt, tree-structure

```
book_category_list=[]
for book_category in BookCategory.objects.filter(parent__isnull = True):
    book_category_list.append(book_category.get_family())**
```

now the `book_category_list` in tree query set format. I need to list categories in a tree structure. So I need to convert this `book_category_list` into dictionary format. BookCategory is an MPTT Model?

Comment: You should share your models and usage of the piece of code you have added here.

Comment: class BookCategory(MPTTModel):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
    path = models.TextField()
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True,db_index=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='childrens')